# Custom grants with Doorkeeper to allow 2fa and social login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, doorkeeper

We want to use the Doorkeeper gem to implement an OAuth provider in our app. However, we use 2-factor auth in the login process, so we need a way to modify the password grant to accept email, password, and a 2fa token (and respond with an appropriate error if the 2fa token is required and missing). We also allow Google social login, so we also need to use a password-like grant which accepts an OAuth 2 code from Google to issue an access token, rather than username/password.

Will this be possible with the Doorkeeper?

Comment: Hey @manknz! Did you find a way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Nope. I wrote my own OAuth 2 implementation in the end, it actually wasn't that hard once you understand the spec.